# Compare object fields in if statement and 2 arraylists

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to do a method that checks if a book is rented and then if the book is in a directory. But I get a variable might not have been initialized error on checkIsBookAvailableToRent. I wonder it means the variable may be the out of scope. Can you help me improve this method, please?

```
package com.company.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookDirectory {

private static List<Book> bookDirectoryList = new ArrayList<Book>();
RentDirectory rentedBooksList = new RentDirectory();
Book book = new Book("");

public boolean isBookAvailableToRent(String title){

    boolean checkIsBookAvailableToRent;
    book.setTitle(title);

    for (Book bookInRentDirectory : rentedBooksList.getRentedBooks()) {
        if (bookInRentDirectory.getTitle().equals(book.getTitle())) {
            checkIsBookAvailableToRent = false;
        }
        else {
            for (Book bookInBookDirectory : bookDirectoryList) {
                if (bookInBookDirectory.getTitle().equals(book.getTitle())) {
                    checkIsBookAvailableToRent = true;
                }
                else {
                    checkIsBookAvailableToRent = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return checkIsBookAvailableToRent;
}

public List<Book> getBookDirectory() {
    return bookDirectoryList;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `checkIsBookAvailableToRent` if `bookDirectoryList` is empty? Or if `rentedBooksList.getRentedBooks()` is empty?

Comment: what @AndyTurner said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `checkIsBookAvailableToRent`, give it a default value, for example,

```
boolean checkIsBookAvailableToRent =  false;
```

This is needed in case your code does not enter the `for` loop for any reason, such as if `rentedBooksList.getRentedBooks()` is empty. In that case, the function wouldn't know what to return.

In general, whenever you do declare variables, it's a good rule of thumb to give them a default value (unless there is a reason not to). That way you don't need to be concerned with errors like this.

Comment: it's a pretty good rule of thumb to initialize your variables and object references right away if there's no reason to specifically not.  It just makes it so you don't have to be concerned about this scenario as often

Comment: Absolutely. I'll add this to my answer, thanks!

Comment: @JulianCleary "if there's no reason to specifically not" the reason specifically not to is that it thwarts definite assignment analysis, which is there to make sure that you have assigned a value in all cases. If you assign a value as a matter when the variable is initialized, you may miss logical corner cases where you don't assign the intended value to the variable. I would flip it round, and say *only assign a value if there is a specific reason to* - as in this case, you need to assign a value in case the loop body is not executed.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I think there was a second mistake the RentDirectory was empty.

Comment: @AndyTurner What you're describing can be avoided in a lot of scenarios by assigning your fallback value to begin, and instead of accounting for every single possible scenario, approach it from the scenarios that should lead to it's assignment away from the fallback value.  It's an opinion of design patterns.  I appreciate your point though, the strategy needs to address the design patterns used.  It's not black and white.